# How to Find Windows MSDN Product Keys

Tags: windows, windows-10, licensing, msdn

I have 2 PCs and one Virtual PC.  I have a Windows MSDN license, and have installed Windows 10 on all of them using a product key from MSDN.  Looking at MSDN, I don't recall which PC has which license and would like to sort this out.

When I run the following in PowerShell:

```
(Get-WmiObject -query ‘select * from SoftwareLicensingService’).OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

On the 2 machines, I get information that doesn't match anything in MSDN.

On the Virtual Machine, OA3xOriginalProductKey is blank.

I think that the PowerShell query might not apply to hand entered Product Keys?  How do I find the product keys I used?

Comment: https://www.techradar.com/best/the-best-windows-10-product-key-finder

Comment: @Moab I did try "magic jellybean" but will give one of these a try